# HelloWorld Rack Program : NoMethodError: undefined method `each'

Tags: ruby, rack

I am trying to execute below HelloWorld rack program and getting an error. Appreciate any help.

ruby version ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-cygwin]

```
# helloworld.rb
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class HelloWorld
 def response
   [200, {}, 'Hello World']
 end
end

class HelloWorldApp
 def self.call(env)
   HelloWorld.new.response
 end
end

Rack::Server.start :app => HelloWorldApp
```

ERROR

```
[2013-11-26 11:23:03] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "Hello World":String
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:72:in `service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change:

```
def response
  [200, {}, 'Hello World']
end
```

to:

```
def response
  [200, {}, ['Hello World']]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd item in the array returned from `#response`  (ie. the `body`) must respond to the `#each` method. Arrays for example, [respond to `#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

From the [Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html):

> The Body
>
> The Body must respond to each and must only yield String values. The
>   Body itself should not be an instance of String, as this will break in
>   Ruby 1.9. If the Body responds to close, it will be called after
>   iteration. If the body is replaced by a middleware after action, the
>   original body must be closed first, if it responds to close. If the
>   Body responds to to_path, it must return a String identifying the
>   location of a file whose contents are identical to that produced by
>   calling each; this may be used by the server as an alternative,
>   possibly more efficient way to transport the response. The Body
>   commonly is an Array of Strings, the application instance itself, or a
>   File-like object.